# Обновление записей

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема: через кнопку происходит отбор записей в таблице (типа Paradox, создана DBD), посредством Query. После отбора в DbGrid показываются только эти записи, если закрыть форму и вызвать её еще раз, записи этиже остаются. Пробовал обновлять через Query. Но ничего не происходит. Как можно такое исправить?

А и еще одно, код на автоматическое добавление следующего номера записи по порядку (типа №). Вот код

```
Form5.Table4.last;
var 
s:integer;
begin
s:=form5.Table4.fieldbyname('ID_Klienta').asinteger+1;
edit1.Text:=inttostr(s);
end;
```

Косяк в том, что код добавляет следующий номер в эдит, но после добавления в таблицу с этим номером, он не изменяется в эдите. К примеру 12 (в эдите) добавили в таблицу и все равно 12 (в эдите). Исправляется, если закрыть форму и открыть заново. Но это как-то не очень, как можно обновить эдит после добавления записи?

П.С.Если что, извиняйте за мою "грамотную речь".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю, весь описанный выше функционал вынесен в отдельную форму (не в главной). И при закрытии дочерней формы, где находятся все компоненты для работы с БД, отобранные данные сохраняются до следующего раза.

Ну начать можно с того, что дочерняя форма не закрывается (при нажатии на красный крестик в правом верхнем углу), она лишь прячется. Это можно проверить с помощью какого-нибудь оконного менеджера. Следствие: все данные на форме сохраняются(при повторном открытии в следующий раз).

**Как решить?**

Для этого достаточно обработать в событии формы **"OnShow"** обновление таблицы и грида:

```
Table1.Refresh;
DBGrid1.Refresh;
```

Comment: мерси помогло)))

Comment: Интересно правда, за что минус?

Comment: Без понятия, я не могу еще + и - ставить...